# How do you add toastr-rails gem to Rails 6 project?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, toastr, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to add the toastr gem to my Rails 6 project. I also have the devise gem installed.

I do not understand webpacker and how to make toastr-rails webpacker friendly.

I have read all the documentation. Don't tell me to read the documentation.

This is what I've tried:

```
yarn add toastr
```

Then in my assets/packs/application.js file, I added:

```
@import 'toastr'
```

And in my assets/stylesheets/application.scss file, I added:

```
*= require_toastr
```

Finally my layouts/application.html.erb has this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <% unless flash.empty? %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <% flash.each do |f| %>
        <% type = f[0].to_s %>
        toastr['<%= type %>']('<%= f[1] %>');
        <% end %>
    </script>
  <% end %>
  <%= yield %>
 </body>
</html>
```

I don't get the toast notifications.
I don't get any notifications.
But this code works on my Rails 4 project.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to add toastr with toastr-rails gem, use asset pipeline instead of webpack.

Here are the steps to add `toastr` with the `webpack`.

1. Add toastr js with yarn

   ```
   yarn add toastr
   ```
2. Require toastr in **app/javascript/packs/application.js**. I added it to the global to avoid errors

   ```
   global.toastr = require("toastr")
   ```
3. Create **app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss** file to import custom or library css files
4. Import toastr css in **app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss**

   ```
   @import 'toastr'
   ```
5. Import **app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss** file in **app/javascript/packs/application.js**

   ```
   import "../stylesheets/application"
   ```
6. I wrote a helper method for flash messages. Add this method to **application_helper.rb** or another helper

   ```
   def toastr_flash
     flash.each_with_object([]) do |(type, message), flash_messages|
       type = 'success' if type == 'notice'
       type = 'error' if type == 'alert'
       text = "<script>toastr.#{type}('#{message}', '', { closeButton: true, progressBar: true })</script>"
       flash_messages << text.html_safe if message
     end.join("\n").html_safe
   end
   ```
7. Add `toastr_flash` method to **layouts/application.html.erb** or wherever you want

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
       <%= yield %>
       <%= toastr_flash %>
     </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: thanks for replying. sadly it it didn't work. I even tried adding semicolons to ```@import 'toastr';``` and  ```import "../stylesheets/application";``` but it didn't work.


but your answer helps me get a feel for webpack. I'm going to keep tinkering

Comment: @davidlee Is it giving an error? (look at console) If so, what is error?

Answer (score 6):

first you need to add toastr to your project

using yarn

```
yarn add toastr
```

using npm

```
npm -i toastr
```

after that you can see in your node_modules the file toastr (node_modules/toastr) inside that have the toastr.scss file and toastr.js file, well let's import it

app/assets/application.scss

```
@import "toastr/toastr";
```

app/javascripts/packs/application.js

```
toastr = require("toastr")
```

or

```
import toastr from 'toastr/toastr';
```